# Can I propagate an event from a label to an anchor link without javascript?

Tags: html, css, events

I am trying to combine 2 tricks in a static website without javascript, if possible.

First, I use a pure css accordion on my menu. It uses radio inputs to control the height of the submenus. So you click on a label and the related submenu expand while others shrink.

Second, I use anchor tags to hide or display specific contents. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18849682/3793161) sums it up.

Bottom line: I have an anchor tag nested in a label tag, like this:

```
   <div class="tab">
    <input id="about-input" type="radio" name="menu">
     <!-- Important part
     –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <label for="about-input">
        <h5 class="nav-item">
             <a href="#about">ABOUT US</a>
        </h5>
    </label>
    <!--–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
     <div class="tab-content">
      <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="#">1</a></h6>
      <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="#">2</a></h6>
      <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="#">3</a></h6>
      <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="#">4</a></h6>
      <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="#">5</a></h6>
     </div>
   </div>
```

As stated in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21637370/3793161):

> In HTML5 CR, the a element is for such reasons defined so that no interactive descendant is allowed, and label counts as interactive.

So I keep the anchor tag in the deepest position. However, the `for` attribute of the label does not trigger if I click on the anchor (which is nested in the label), and if I click on the rest of the label, I am outside the anchor (and the anchor tag is not updated)

**EDIT: As requested, I wrote a snippet with the css. In this version, the link takes over in the first 2 menu items.I removed the link in the 3th and 4th menu items so you can see that the menu expands/reduce using the `:checked` pseudo selector, but of course the section anchored wont appear (no link).**

```css
#why,
#about,
#why2,
#about2{
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
#why:target,#about:target,#why2:target,#about2:target {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.tab input:checked ~ .tab-content {
  max-height: 25em;
}
.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .35s;
  -o-transition: max-height .35s;
  transition: max-height .35s;
}
.tab input,
#menu-input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: grey;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  background-color: cyan;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.tab input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="tab  expandable">
      <input id="about-input" type="checkbox">
      <label id="about-label" for="about-input">
        <a href="#about">
          <h5 class="nav-item">ABOUT US</h5>
        </a>
      </label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="about/purpose">Purpose</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="about/1">1</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="about/2">2</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="about/3">3</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="anout/4">4</a></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab  expandable">
      <input id="why-input" type="checkbox">
      <label id="why-label" for="why-input">
        <a href="#why">
          <h5 class="nav-item">WHY</h5>
        </a>
      </label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="why/purpose">why is that?</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="why/1">1</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="why/2">2)</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="why/3">3</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="why/4">4</a></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="tab  expandable">
      <input id="about2-input" type="checkbox">
      <label id="about2-label" for="about2-input">
          <h5 class="nav-item">ABOUT US2</h5>
      </label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="about/purpose">Purpose2</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="about/1">1</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="about/2">2</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="about/3">3</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="anout/4">4</a></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab  expandable">
      <input id="why2-input" type="checkbox">
      <label id="why2-label" for="why2-input">
          <h5 class="nav-item">WHY2</h5>
      </label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="why2/purpose">why2 is that?</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="why2/1">1</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="why2/2">2)</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="why2/3">3</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="why2/4">4</a></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <section id="about">
      Quod cum ita sit, paucae domus studiorum seriis cultibus antea celebratae nunc ludibriis ignaviae torpentis exundant, vocali sonu, perflabili tinnitu fidium resultantes. denique pro philosopho cantor et in locum oratoris doctor artium ludicrarum accitur
      et bybliothecis sepulcrorum ritu in perpetuum clausis organa fabricantur hydraulica, et lyrae ad speciem carpentorum ingentes tibiaeque et histrionici gestus instrumenta non levia. Inter haec Orfitus praefecti potestate regebat urbem aeternam ultra

    </section>
    <section id="why">

      modum delatae dignitatis sese efferens insolenter, vir quidem prudens et forensium negotiorum oppido gnarus, sed splendore liberalium doctrinarum minus quam nobilem decuerat institutus, quo administrante seditiones sunt concitatae graves ob inopiam
      vini: huius avidis usibus vulgus intentum ad motus asperos excitatur et crebros. At nunc si ad aliquem bene nummatum tumentemque ideo honestus advena salutatum introieris, primitus tamquam exoptatus suscipieris et interrogatus multa coactusque mentiri,
      miraberis numquam antea visus summatem virum tenuem te sic enixius observantem, ut paeniteat ob haec bona tamquam praecipua non vidisse ante decennium Romam.

    </section>
     <section id="about2">
      Quod cum ita sit, paucae domus studiorum seriis cultibus antea celebratae nunc ludibriis ignaviae torpentis exundant, vocali sonu, perflabili tinnitu fidium resultantes. denique pro philosopho cantor et in locum oratoris doctor artium ludicrarum accitur
      et bybliothecis sepulcrorum ritu in perpetuum clausis organa fabricantur hydraulica, et lyrae ad speciem carpentorum ingentes tibiaeque et histrionici gestus instrumenta non levia. Inter haec Orfitus praefecti potestate regebat urbem aeternam ultra

    </section>
    <section id="why2">

      modum delatae dignitatis sese efferens insolenter, vir quidem prudens et forensium negotiorum oppido gnarus, sed splendore liberalium doctrinarum minus quam nobilem decuerat institutus, quo administrante seditiones sunt concitatae graves ob inopiam
      vini: huius avidis usibus vulgus intentum ad motus asperos excitatur et crebros. At nunc si ad aliquem bene nummatum tumentemque ideo honestus advena salutatum introieris, primitus tamquam exoptatus suscipieris et interrogatus multa coactusque mentiri,
      miraberis numquam antea visus summatem virum tenuem te sic enixius observantem, ut paeniteat ob haec bona tamquam praecipua non vidisse ante decennium Romam.

    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to propagate the event properly? Or a workaround?

Comment: Is this rather ugly collection of CSS hacks really better than just using JavaScript? Which is a tool designed for that sort of thing.

Comment: I know that would be way quicker/cleaner. This is just one of these "can it be done" questions bugging me. I am almost certain it cannot be done properly without js but still, you never know.

Comment: Put the radio button inside the label?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, I just tried but nope, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I keep the anchor tag in the deepest position. However, the `for` attribute of **the label does not trigger if I click on the anchor** (which is nested in the label), and if I click on the rest of the label, I am outside the anchor (and the anchor tag is not updated)
>
> Is there a way to propagate the event properly? Or a workaround?

**Layout**

1. A `<label>` with `for` to a `<button>` on #3.
2. An `<a>`nchor that's targeting a hidden `<section>` located outside of `<label>`.
3. A `<button>` linked to the `<label>` at #1.
4. A `<h5>`

**Sequence of Events**

1. Click the on the edge of `<label>` (pink square-yellow dashed border).
2. Note under the `<label>` the content of `<section>`(`#content:target` appears).
3. This proves that yes it is possible to exploit the link between `<label for>` and a form element `<button>`
4. Now repeat process, but start by clicking `<a>`, you should have the same result.

**Capturing**............................**Bubbling**

...........................................

.**Phase**.................................**Phase**

...`event.currentTarget`...

`<label>`..............................`<label>`

....▼..........................................▲

... event triggers.................

..`<a>`...................................`<a>`

....▼......................................▲

......event triggers.......

`<button>`.................`<button>`

....▼..........................▲

..`<h5>`....................`<h5>`

.......................

........`event.target`

........**Event Target**

1. `<label>`#1 clicked which is linked to `<button>`#3
2. On the way down the event chain, `<a>`#2 is passed by onto it's way to `<button>`#3
3. Target phase happens
4. On the bubbling phase, `<a>`#2 is triggered and the targeted `section#content` appears.

#### SNIPPET

```js
// For testing purposes
/*$('.link').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.currentTarget) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.tagName);
  }
});*/
```

```css
label {
  border: 3px dashed gold;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.2);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.link {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.2);
}
.button {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 75px;
  width: 50px;
}
.title {
  border: 3px dotted blue;
}
#content {
  display: none;
}
#content:target {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="test">
  <a href="#content" class='link'>ANCHOR
    <button id='test' class='button'>
BUTTON
      <h5 class="title">TITLE</h5>
    </button>
  </a>
LABEL
</label>
<section id='content'>...:::CONTENT:::...</section>
```

Comment: I did try it quickly when you posted this answer. It looked it it didn't work with an input (I didn't try with a button). You think it is worth trying again with an input? Or would you think of a button related pseudo element that would allow me to replicate the radio/checkbox input `:checked` css trick? By the way, thanks for that answer, and have an happy new year :)

Comment: You are welcome and Happy New Year to you as well, sir. The point of this demo is to show that by layering the elements in conjunction with the use of the `:target` pseudo-selector you can trigger behavior like basic JavaScript does (in a limited fashion of course.) The `:checked` pseudo-selector is a better choice but involves more CSS and a stricter placement of layout. It involves the `for` attribute, `:checked` pseudo-selector and gives you two way switching between 2 states. With `:target` you get a one-way switch to a state, but it's possible to have multi-states given more `#a:target`s.

Comment: BTW, I forgot to mention, the `for` attribute is exclusively for form nodes to associate functionality with other form nodes. So `for` will not work with an anchor, but ids do in conjunction with `:target` (already discussed), and iframes, etc.

Comment: Ok there is a misunderstanding: I want to use both `:target` and `:checked` pseudo selectors. `:target` is used just as you did, it allows me to display sections of content depending on the clicked link. `:checked`, related to a `for` attribute checking a radio input that is used to expand or reduce, using css (e.g. `input:checked ~ .tab-content`, the min-height of my sub-menu. I just retried without success. Even when I nest the radio input in the anchor link, the `for` of the label doesn't trigger it.

Comment: I'll need your CSS and the actual results, like for instance sequence of events and behavior of how you expect things to go and what is happening instead.

Comment: I'm having trouble following what you are saying. It's too hard to remember `input:checked ~ .tab-content` where there's no CSS.

Comment: *However, the for attribute of the label does not trigger if I click on the anchor* But my code does, did you notice if you click anywhere on the label or anchor, the content on the bottom toggles off and on?

Comment: I made you a snippet. See my edited question. I replicated your code with the input but I couldn't make it work (the input value does not switch to "checked"). Maybe the working example will help. Thank you again.

Comment: It also does not work when I edit your example directly to replace the button with an input type radio or checkbox.

Comment: What browser are you using? Because on Chrome PC I can open #3 and #4 menu and see and click the links within dropdown menus.

Comment: I'm on Firefox. But #3 and #4 sub-menu links are not the links I am talking about. The links I am talking about are those wrapped by the labels in #1 and #2 (e.g. #1 link is the direct child of `#about-label`). As you can see, I can't both use the `for` attribute of the label and the link contained, or the other way around, i.e. if the link contains the label

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132647/discussion-between-zer00ne-and-billybobbonnet).

Comment: @Billybobbonnet My service is going in and out and I guess it's failing on chat, sorry.