# How to avoid that overflow makes a menu flickering during css animation

Tags: html, css

I made a vertical menu with an underline effect on hover of the menu items.

It didn't work in snippet but the effect ([taken from here](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-sliding-underline/)) is as follows:

```
/* LEFT TO RIGHT */
.sliding-u-l-r {
display: inline-block;
}
.sliding-u-l-r:after {
content: '';
display: block;
height: 3px;
width: 0;
background: transparent;
transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.sliding-u-l-r:hover:after {
width: 100%;
background: blue;
}
```

In Chrome only, I have a 4 pixel range in the browser height where, when you hover an item, during the animation, the height of the menu changes quickly. It leads to a flickering scrolling bar (appearing and disappearing very fast).

The height isn't really changing, and I don't know how to avoid that. Of course, hiding overflow is not a good answer, unless it is disabled only during the animation.

Here is the snippet (still working on it > except the caret pseudo element placement, this is the exact same case than my real case, except that here, the issue wont occur.)

```css
#why,
#about,
#how,
#when,
#where,
#what {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
#why:target,
#about:target,
#why2:target,
#about2:target {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.tab input:checked ~ .tab-content {
  max-height: 25em;
}
.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .35s;
  -o-transition: max-height .35s;
  transition: max-height .35s;
}
.tab input,
#menu-input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: grey;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  background-color: cyan;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.tab input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tab input:checked ~ .tab-content,
#about:target *#about-menu {
    max-height: 25em;
}
/* Icon */

.tab label::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: width .35s ease, background-color .35s ease;
    -o-transition:  width .35s ease, background-color .35s ease;
    transition:  width .35s ease, background-color .35s ease;
}
.tab.expandable input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
    content: "\25BC";
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tab.expandable input[type=checkbox]:hover + label::after {
    color: #1EAEDB;
}
.tab.expandable input[type=checkbox]:checked:hover + label::after {
    color: #555;
}
.tab.expandable input[type=checkbox]:checked + label h5,
.tab.expandable input[type=checkbox]:checked + h5 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label h5,
input[type=checkbox]:checked + h5 {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tab.expandable input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label h5:after,
input[type=checkbox]:checked + h5 a:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: #222;
}
.nav-item a,
.nav-sub-item a,
.tab a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav-item a:after,
.nav-sub-item a:after,
label h5:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.nav-item a:hover,
.nav-sub-item a:hover,
label h5:hover,
input[type=checkbox]:hover + label h5 {
    color: #1EAEDB;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-item a.selected,
.nav-sub-item a.selected,
label h5.selected {} .nav-item a:hover:after,
.nav-sub-item a:hover:after,
label h5:hover:after,
input[type=checkbox]:hover + label h5:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: #1EAEDB;
}
.nav-item a.selected:after,
.nav-sub-item a.selected:after,
label h5.selected:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: #555;
}
.tab label .nav-item {
    /*/  margin-bottom: 0px;*/
}
/* Acordeon styles */

.tab {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tab input,
#menu-input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.tab label,
#menu-label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.tab-content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height .35s;
    -o-transition: max-height .35s;
    transition: max-height .35s;
}
.tab-content h6 {
    margin: 1em;
}
/* :checked */

.tab input:checked ~ .tab-content,
#about:target *#about-menu {
    max-height: 25em;
}
/* Icon */

.tab label::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -o-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}
.tab.expandable input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
    content: "\25BC";
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tab.expandable input[type=checkbox]:hover + label::after {
    color: #1EAEDB;
}
.tab.expandable input[type=checkbox]:checked:hover + label::after {
    color: #555;
}
.tab.expandable input[type=checkbox]:checked + label h5,
.tab.expandable input[type=checkbox]:checked + h5 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label h5,
input[type=checkbox]:checked + h5 {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tab.expandable input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label h5:after,
input[type=checkbox]:checked + h5 a:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: #222;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="tab  expandable">
      <input id="about-input" type="checkbox">
      <label id="about-label" for="about-input">
        <h5 class="nav-item">ABOUT</h5>
      </label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="about/purpose">Purpose2</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="about/1">1</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="about/2">2</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="about/3">3</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="anout/4">4</a></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab  expandable">
      <input id="why-input" type="checkbox">
      <label id="why-label" for="why-input">
        <h5 class="nav-item">WHY</h5>
      </label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="why/purpose">why2 is that?</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="why/1">1</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="why/2">2)</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="why/3">3</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="why/4">4</a></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab  expandable">
      <input id="how-input" type="checkbox">
      <label id="how-label" for="how-input">
        <h5 class="nav-item">how</h5>
      </label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="how/purpose">Purpose2</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="how/1">1</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="how/2">2</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="how/3">3</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="how/4">4</a></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab  expandable">
      <input id="when-input" type="checkbox">
      <label id="when-label" for="when-input">
        <h5 class="nav-item">when</h5>
      </label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="when/purpose">why2 is that?</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="when/1">1</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="when/2">2)</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="when/3">3</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="when/4">4</a></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab  expandable">
      <input id="where-input" type="checkbox">
      <label id="where-label" for="where-input">
        <h5 class="nav-item">where</h5>
      </label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="where/purpose">Purpose2</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="where/1">1</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="where/2">2</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="where/3">3</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="where/4">4</a></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab  expandable">
      <input id="what-input" type="checkbox">
      <label id="what-label" for="what-input">
        <h5 class="nav-item">what</h5>
      </label>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="what/purpose">why2 is that?</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="what/1">1</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="what/2">2)</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="what/3">3</a></h6>
        <h6 class="nav-sub-item"><a href="what/4">4</a></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <section id="about">
      Quod cum ita sit, paucae domus studiorum seriis cultibus antea celebratae nunc ludibriis ignaviae torpentis exundant, vocali sonu, perflabili tinnitu fidium resultantes. denique pro philosopho cantor et in locum oratoris doctor artium ludicrarum accitur
      et bybliothecis sepulcrorum ritu in perpetuum clausis organa fabricantur hydraulica, et lyrae ad speciem carpentorum ingentes tibiaeque et histrionici gestus instrumenta non levia. Inter haec Orfitus praefecti potestate regebat urbem aeternam ultra

    </section>
    <section id="why">

      modum delatae dignitatis sese efferens insolenter, vir quidem prudens et forensium negotiorum oppido gnarus, sed splendore liberalium doctrinarum minus quam nobilem decuerat institutus, quo administrante seditiones sunt concitatae graves ob inopiam vini:
      huius avidis usibus vulgus intentum ad motus asperos excitatur et crebros. At nunc si ad aliquem bene nummatum tumentemque ideo honestus advena salutatum introieris, primitus tamquam exoptatus suscipieris et interrogatus multa coactusque mentiri,
      miraberis numquam antea visus summatem virum tenuem te sic enixius observantem, ut paeniteat ob haec bona tamquam praecipua non vidisse ante decennium Romam.

    </section>
    <section id="about2">
      Quod cum ita sit, paucae domus studiorum seriis cultibus antea celebratae nunc ludibriis ignaviae torpentis exundant, vocali sonu, perflabili tinnitu fidium resultantes. denique pro philosopho cantor et in locum oratoris doctor artium ludicrarum accitur
      et bybliothecis sepulcrorum ritu in perpetuum clausis organa fabricantur hydraulica, et lyrae ad speciem carpentorum ingentes tibiaeque et histrionici gestus instrumenta non levia. Inter haec Orfitus praefecti potestate regebat urbem aeternam ultra

    </section>
    <section id="why2">

      modum delatae dignitatis sese efferens insolenter, vir quidem prudens et forensium negotiorum oppido gnarus, sed splendore liberalium doctrinarum minus quam nobilem decuerat institutus, quo administrante seditiones sunt concitatae graves ob inopiam vini:
      huius avidis usibus vulgus intentum ad motus asperos excitatur et crebros. At nunc si ad aliquem bene nummatum tumentemque ideo honestus advena salutatum introieris, primitus tamquam exoptatus suscipieris et interrogatus multa coactusque mentiri,
      miraberis numquam antea visus summatem virum tenuem te sic enixius observantem, ut paeniteat ob haec bona tamquam praecipua non vidisse ante decennium Romam.

    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this - in Chrome or Firefox applying the above CSS to a DIV nothing changes in height or position in either state (including pseudo elements). A more complete example (a fiddle etc.) or knowing what browser this occurs in may be assistance. I put together a quick fiddle which might be a good starting point and was testing by lining the div up with the bottom of the screen then mousing over: https://jsfiddle.net/1zjg1u8b/3/

Comment: Updated the question with the browser (chrome only). The tricky thing is that even when I replicate the issue, no element seem to change its height. Assuming it was webkit related it tried the solution mentionned here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461441/prevent-flicker-on-webkit-transition-of-webkit-transform but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you make a pen of the nav? I cant replicate either with the code provided.

Comment: Thanks for the update, however I still can't seem to replicate putting it on both the bottom and right borders of the page in Chrome (Windows). Maybe is OS specific or other factors on page contributing to the issue?

Comment: I will try to make a pen, but it will be a pain to replicate. I'll keep you posted, thank you for your help guys :)

Comment: Hi, none of your solutions worked, but I couldn't reproduce the problem either. If you want to take a look to the real version here it is: https://1ty.me/9LqCJzi (1 time link, tell me if someone else clicked it). You need then 100% zoom and a window height of 632px when no menu item is expanded. On Chrome only. You will see the problem appear when hovering the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` on the pseudo

```css
/* LEFT TO RIGHT */

.sliding-u-l-r {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.sliding-u-l-r:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.sliding-u-l-r:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliding-u-l-r">
  Some text
</div>
```

Or `transform: scale`

```css
/* LEFT TO RIGHT */

.sliding-u-l-r {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sliding-u-l-r:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  margin-left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  transform: scale(0,1);
  background: transparent;
  transition: transform .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.sliding-u-l-r:hover:after {
  transform: scale(1,1);
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliding-u-l-r">
  Some text
</div>
```

Comment: I tried both solutions, but none worked. I wanted to put up a snippet before coming back to you, but I had to work on another project. I will come back shortly with a snippet. Meanwhile I can tell you that it is the same layout than in the snippet I posted there :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40916644/can-i-propagate-an-event-from-a-label-to-an-anchor-link-without-javascript/40919359 there is just no css effect mentionned here. Also consider that it is a Chrome only bug. If I cant reproduce the issue, I will at least post a gif of what it looks like. Thank you for the follow up

Comment: @Billybobbonnet Since it works in both my above snippets, update with a snippet of your own, and when, notify me and I'll have a look

Comment: In my version, both your snippets and my solution work concerning the CSS effect. The issue occurs only when the screen, in Chrome, has a specific height (when the menu scrollbar just appeared). In this case the menu is blinking because the scrollbar appears and disappear during the 0.5 sec of the hover effect (which is working fine in itself).

Comment: @Billybobbonnet That most likely will be solved by changing `top: 100%` to `bottom: 0`, and by doing that the pseudo element stays within the text element itself. Updated my first sample.

Comment: @Billybobbonnet Didn't it work with my update? .. If, consider an upvote and an accept, if not, what can I adjust to make that possible?